# On the effect of action of product of permutation group on vectors

Tags: permutations, tensors, group-actions

I am confused with the following permutation. Suppose $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$ the permutation group of order $n$. Define $\sigma.(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)=(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\dots, x_{\sigma(n)})$. (it affects on the indices directly, no matter where is it) Using this definition what is the flaw of the following?
$$(\tau\sigma).(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)=\tau.(\sigma.(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n))=\tau.(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\dots, x_{\sigma(n)})=(x_{\tau(\sigma(1))},x_{\tau(\sigma(2))},\dots, x_{\tau(\sigma(n)}))$$

On the other hand, one can compute it as follows (the correct one):

$$(\tau\sigma).(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)=\tau.(\sigma.(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n))=\tau.(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\dots, x_{\sigma(n)})\stackrel{\text{let } y_i=x_{\sigma(i)}}{====}(y_{\tau(1)},y_{\tau(2)},\dots, y_{\tau(n)})=(x_{ \sigma(\tau(1))},x_{ \sigma(\tau(2))},\dots, x_{\sigma(\tau(n)})).$$

I think the confusion point is because of I am acting the $\tau$ and $\sigma$ in wrong order but I don't know how to justify it just using the definition $\sigma.(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)=(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\dots, x_{\sigma(n)})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subtlety is that if you want to act on the subscript indices "*directly*", this needs to be a right action (not a left action). If you write it like

$$ (x_1,\dots,x_n) \cdot \sigma = (x_{\sigma(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)}) $$

Then I think it will work out.

If you want to keep it a left action, you should use the inverse permutation:

$$ \sigma \cdot (x_1,\dots,x_n) = (x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\dots,x_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}) $$

Now when you evaluate $y_{\tau^{-1}(1)} = y_{\sigma^{-1}(\tau^{-1}(1))}$, this works, because $\sigma^{-1} \circ \tau^{-1} = (\tau \circ \sigma)^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't understand that why my action is right action? you meant that my action isn't really an action?

Comment: There are two different notions of an "action". A left action is a map $G \times X \to X$, where you write $gx$ to mean the group element $g$ acting on the element $x$. For a right action, it's a map $X \times G \to X$, where you write $xg$ for $g$ acting on $x$. For a left action, $(gh)x = g(hx)$, and for a right action, $x(gh) = (xg)h$.

Comment: In your example, the original thing you proposed is not an action at all (in either sense). This is exactly the discrepancy you pointed out in your original post.

Comment: So why in the [Loring TU's Book, a similar action](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Manifolds/xQsTJJGsgs4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA24&printsec=frontcover) is a left action?

Comment: In the book, the permutations are acting on functions. In your example, the permutations are acting on tuples (which in the book are like just the arguments/inputs to the functions). As you see in the proof in the book, when you act on functions, when computing $\tau (\sigma f)$, you apply $\tau$ to the inputs first (in the first line of the calculation in Lemma 3.11). But when you act on tuples, to compute $\tau ( \sigma (x_1,\dots,x_n))$, you act by $\sigma$ first.